# Faster Solve for Fermat 4n+1 conjecture

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, number-theory, prime-numbers

Assuming that Fermat `4n+1` conjecture (each prime of the form `4n+1` is the sum of two squares) is true then I like to solve the equation in the fastest possible form.

```
fermatQ[z_] := 
 Length[Solve[x^2 + y^2 == z && x > 0 && y > 0 && x > y, {x, y}, 
    Integers]] == 1
```

---

```
n = RandomPrime[10^1000]
7204820541697853265697482198302184350747317334028070603629009839116252110492095578256567601106541188796967599300930463571131759731713652353047579003939845222202423352007102653912639893572595606320600084613647266601717191253462990524380427645290376322143085916721648030108591154681102352260206273871572063237796538519461643983233381100630087701623080830334878529319816938438525254877567479353234371918939199585631244203057530334523235226572902803801085582846927846832856652925979381175382144232563160719058478946717172490138082439192330136929995648881640700486082783629709282614697667884919440294962926788805345569631546029257495702381802397055578335502287473342083514426712460325643772655909154310734572274430109077955105556789724468724642608390802045303940792665411216800131523990931511413428660061711347430190867360920645531069644270820680156683794692381221310012472305068130266122993566902672115038607482079495349772492239436104516688041844051770082711796572639884658459765037703578841572775761721

Divisible[(n - 1), 4]    
True
```

---

```
Timing[fermatQ[n]]

{0.296875, True}

Timing[PrimeQ[n]]

{0.203125, True}

Timing[Length[PowersRepresentations[n, 2, 2]] == 1]

{0.687500, True}
```

1. Can we optimize `fermatQ` to solve it faster?
2. Can we say to `Solve` to halt and return upon finding the first `k` solutions ? (Not to compute them all and extract the first `k` solutions)

**Updated**

Added timing for MMA built-in `PowersRepresentations` which is slower than `Solve`.

**Update 2**

Based on @KennyColnago answer, we can write a one line formula but yet the timing is the same (everything behind the scene seems to be equal):

```
ModularRootPrimeQ[n_] := Length[PowerModList[-1, 1/2, n]] == 2

Select[Prime[Range[4, 1000000]], 
 Mod[#, 4] == 1 && ! ModularRootPrimeQ[#] &]

{} // Checked the first million primes and found no counterpart
```

If you run the same over all 4m+1 numbers, you'll get all 4m+1 primes with only prime powers:

```
Select[Range[1000000], 
 Mod[#, 4] == 1 && ! PrimePowerQ[#] && 
   ModularRootPrimeQ[#] && ! PrimeQ[#] &]

{} // If you remove the condition !PrimePowerQ[#] , only prime powers will appear here.
```

Comment: Could use `FactorInteger[m, GaussianIntegers->True]`. If `m` is a prime of the form `4n+1` then this will factor it as a product of conjugate Gaussian primes.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Timing is the same

Comment: Probably means `Solve` is doing essentially the same thing under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

You can use`FindInstance`to specify the number of solutions desired as in

```
FindInstance[{p == x^2 + y^2, x>0, y>0, x>y}, {x, y}, Integers, 1]
```

for large random prime`p`. However, the following Cornacchia algorithm is faster than`FindInstance`or`Solve`, on my machine, and perhaps is open to optimization...

```
Cornacchia[p_] :=
   Block[{r, a, s},
      r = Select[PowerModList[-1, 1/2, p], #<p/2&];
      If[r == {}, {},
         Select[Table[a=p; s=r[[i]]; 
                      While[a^2>=p, {s,a} = {a,Mod[s,a]}];
                      {a, Sqrt[p-a^2]},
                   {i, Length[r]}],
         IntegerQ[#[[2]]]&]
      ]]
```

The timing test I used was as follows, YMMV.

```
With[{p=Select[RandomPrime[10^200, 50], Mod[#,4]==1&]},
     Print[p];
     {AbsoluteTiming[Map[Cornacchia, p]],
      AbsoluteTiming[
         Map[Solve[{# == x^2 + y^2, x>0, y>0, x>y}, {x,y}, Integers]&, p]],
      AbsoluteTiming[
         Map[FindInstance[{# == x^2 + y^2, x>0, y>0, x>y}, {x,y}, Integers, 1]&, p]]
     }]
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but the timing in my larger 2K numbers are the same as Solve

Comment: My machine still runs `Cornacchia` faster than `Solve` on the larger numbers but, as I said, your timings may vary. The `FactorInteger` method of @DanielLichtblau should not be dismissed so quickly; it is significantly faster than all so far. Perhaps if you could optimize the `Cornacchia` algorithm, since its inner workings are visible and not a black box like `Solve`, then we would all benefit.

Comment: I've added new findings

Comment: Here is a shorter variant. `With[{r = PowerMod[-1, 1/2, p]}, GCD[p, r + I]]`. But it's not any faster as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks! Your PowerMod formulation is compact and much, much faster than the awkward JacobiSymbol equivalent I was using in another non-Cornacchia approach.